# Is the number of poles of an open loop transfer function the same after closing the loop? Why?

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

My textbook says that it is, but if OLTF is

$$G(s)$$

and CLTF is

$$\frac{G(s)} {1+G(s)H(s)}$$

I don't see why the number of poles would have to be the same.

Comment: If $G(s)$ is the OLTF then the "standard" CLTF would be $G(s)/(1 + G(s))$, which should clarify that statement. In your question, it is unclear what you denote with $H(s)$.

Comment: @SampleTime It's what I saw on Wikipedia page about CLTF. If I understand it correctly, H(s) is the transfer function of the sensor. Assuming H(s) = 1, wouldn't there still be 1 extra pole? All the poles of G(s) and one new pole in s for which G(s) = -1?

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is only true for the case that the sensor transfer function, $H(s) = 1$, which can in many cases be assumed.

Then, given the open loop transfer function $G(s)$, the closed loop transfer function $G_c(s)$ is

$$
G_c(s) = \frac{G(s)}{1 + G(s) H(s)} = \frac{G(s)}{1 + G(s)}
$$

Now write $G(s) = N(s)/D(s)$, where $N(s)$ is the numerator polynomial and $D(s)$ the denominator polynomial. Then, write $G_c(s)$ as

$$
G_c(s) = \frac{\frac{N(s)}{D(s)}}{1 + \frac{N(s)}{D(s)}} = \frac{N(s)}{D(s) + N(s)}
$$

So in the denominator of $G_c(s)$, you are effectively adding two polynomials, namely $D(s)$ and $N(s)$. Let $n_D$ denote the degree of $D(s)$ and $n_N$ the degree of $N(s)$.

For $G(s)$ to be causal (and therefore to exist in "real-life"), $n_N \leq n_D$ is necessary. So if you add $N(s)$ to $D(s)$, its degree cannot increase.

**Example**: Lets take an example with $n_N = 1$ and $n_D = 2$:

$$
\begin{align}
N(s) &= s + 1 \\
D(s) &= s^2 + 5 s + 1
\end{align}
$$

So you get

$$
\begin{align}
D(s) + N(s) &= (s^2 + 5 s + 1) + (s + 1) \\
&= s^2 + (5 + 1)s + (1 + 1) \\
&= s^2 + 6 s + 2
\end{align}
$$

So $D(s) + N(s)$ is still a second order polynomial, just as $D(s)$, so they have the same number of roots and therefore, $G_c(s)$ has the same number of poles as $G(s)$.

Comment: Wouldn't D(s) also have to be nonzero for

$$\frac{\frac{N(s)}{D(s)}}{1 + \frac{N(s)}{D(s)}} = \frac{N(s)}{D(s) + N(s)}$$

to be true?

Comment: In this case, $D(s) = 0$ is a removable singularity, so it is valid to simplify the fraction like that (though using an equal sign might not be 100% correct).